# Redirecting from asp.net web form to mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, response.redirect

i am in a subfolder called "paypal" and im trying to redirect to my mvc page.  I have tried these 3 ways  The page I am trying to redirect form is a webform

```
Response.Redirect("../../SubscriptionView/Success/" + pdt.TransactionId.ToString());

Response.Redirect("../SubscriptionView/Success/" + pdt.TransactionId.ToString());

Response.Redirect("~/SubscriptionView/Success/" + pdt.TransactionId.ToString());
```

and keep getting

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

... **.com:80/paypal/subscriptionview/success/**...

See how the redirect has not moved up from the paypal directory?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be using Response.Redirect in MVC. Try [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.108).aspx) instead.

Comment: I created paypal listener and did it with a webform following their suggestions... thinking now i can move it to a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to get it working.

```
 UrlHelper urlHelp = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
                    response.Redirect(urlHelp.Action("PaymentError", "SubscriptionView", new { mailId = mailId }));
```

This returned me from the aspx page that i needed process the response from paypal back to my controller