# How to Redirect From WebForms to a MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, buttonclick

I use an ASP.net WebForm in a MVC application.
I need to redirect to a MVC View or to an ActionResult method in a Controller from WebForm Button Click Event.
Is there a way to do this?

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{                                                             
    //Method in MVC Controller                                                                 
    //Rest of the code                                                    
}
```

Tried as below to redirect to a method in Controller:

```cs
protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                    
    Response.Redirect("~/BreakdownReports/Index",false);
    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();                        
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479409/redirecting-from-asp-net-web-form-to-mvc-4

Comment: @DivyaAgrawal Thank you for the help. Your solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

try it I redirected  from .aspx  to MVC controller page

```
 protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                    
        var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
         Response.Redirect(page.GetRouteUrl("Set hereDefaultroute", 
          new { Controller="BreakdownReports", Action="Index"}), false);               
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Response.Redirect("BreakdownReports/Index");
```

also

```
Response.Redirect("./BreakdownReports/Index");
```